# Using Event Callback in a foreach loop in Blazor

Tags: c#, foreach, event-handling, blazor, func

I don't know if this is a bug, but I'm getting an unexpected behaviour. I get it, when I modify microsoft doc "EventCallback" [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

**Shared/Child.razor:**

[image]

```
<h3>child</h3>
<p>
    @{
        object obj = new();
    }
    @foreach(var item in DataSource)
    {
        obj = item;
        <button @onclick="() => OnClickCallback(obj)">
            @item
        </button>
    }
</p>

@code {
public List<string> DataSource = new List<string>{"cow", "dog", "pig", "rat"};

[Parameter]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public Func<object, Task> OnClickCallback { get; set; } = DoNothingAsync;

private static async Task DoNothingAsync(object param)
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

}

**Shared/Parent.razor**:

[image]

```
    @page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<Child @ref="Child">
    Bla bla bla
</Child>


@code{
    private string message;
    private Child Child;
        
        

protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
     Child.OnClickCallback = ShowMessage;
}

private async Task ShowMessage(object str)
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", (string)str);
}
}
```

**Expected Result**: I get a list of buttons with different labels with the following Labels => "cow", "dog", "pig", "rat". And when I click on any of the button, I should get a pop-up alert displaying the label text of the button I clicked.

**Actual Result**: I get a list of buttons with different labels with the following Labels => "cow", "dog", "pig", "rat". But when I click on the button, I get a pop-up alert displaying "rat" regardless of whatever button I'm clicking.

I don't know, is this a bug? If it is not a bug, how do I get my expected result?

Comment: In the future, post all code as text. Easier to format and quote from.

Comment: Even the actual "rat" is a surprise, `OnClickCallback  = ShowMessageHolder` does not compile.

Comment: @HenkHolterman noted, I'll post in text next time. I looked at it again and I discovered that it was a scoping issue. "obj" was outside the foreach loop (although I don't know why that should matter), but I brought it into the foreach loop. and it works now. Thanks

Comment: @ObaigbonaJoel, folks here are voting to close your question. I guess it is due to embedding images instead of typing the code. Please, remove the images, and type the code instead.

Comment: @enet but I put both code and image up there (the 2 options are available for anyone's preference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to variable scoping in lamda expression.

Change

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

@for (var i = 0; i < DataSource.Count; i++)
{
    var local_i = i;
    var local_v = @DataSource[local_i];
    <div>
       <button 
       @onclick="() => OnClickCallback(local_v)">@DataSource[i]
       </button>
    </div>
}
```

In codebehind

```
@code {

public List<string> DataSource = new List<string>{"cow", "dog", "pig", "rat"};

   private async Task OnClickCallback(string s)
   {
   Console.WriteLine(s);
   await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", s);  
   }

 }
```

[**Proof here**](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wcEqvxbl59OgcFJk46)

With foreach it can be written like this. See [**here**](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GmkAbnbo54JZYeAN45).

```
@{ int x = 0;}
@foreach (var data in DataSource)
{
    var local_v = @DataSource[x];
    <div><button
          @onclick="() => OnClickCallback(local_v)">@data</button></div>
    x++;
}
```

Comment: "obj" was outside the foreach loop (although I don't know why that should matter), but I brought it into the foreach loop. and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Scoping and the local_i trick apply to  `for()` loops but not to `foreach()`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't know about the "local_i trick", but with regards to scoping, the results I'm getting says otherwise, try running my code above and compare the result to when you move "obj" into the foreach loop

Comment: hey @ObaigbonaJoel - updated answer with `foreach`

Comment: @HenkHolterman - not sure why it was downvoted, however I have updated my answer with foreach, I know that scoping is only for for loop, that's why in my previous answer it was with for loop only.

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar Your answer has helped which was why I marked it as the correct answer, I'm not sure who or why it was downvoted. My issue has been resolved and it was weirdly related to scoping, (which is why I'm surprised) when I declare "obj" outside the foreach loop - I get crazy result, but if I declare it within the foreach loop - it works fine.

Comment: `Scoping and the local_i trick apply to for() loops but not to foreach()` absolutely wrong. Try to understand what is going on. The issue is one of scope, and the answerer of this question is right.

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar, you are correct, and HenkHolterman is wrong

Comment: This is so weird. Completely unexpected behaviour. Why do I have to create a local variable for this to work. And I wasted almost an hour to figure out why my code doesn't work.